# How to Use Download Functionality in a while Loop?

Tags: loops, flutter, while-loop

I have below code, the objective is to put a download button below each image and download that particular image on being clicked. however when I run the code, for all buttons it is attempting to download Image number 9, whereas the loop run tills only i =8 that is for 8 images. Please help how to resolve this issue?

```
Widget getWidgets(int index, String name) {
  List<Widget> list = new List<Widget>();
  int i = 1;
  while (i <= index) {
    list.add(new Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(
          height: 15.0,
        ),
        BeforeAfter(
          beforeImage: Image.asset(
            'assets/$name/OG$i.jpg',
            //fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
          afterImage: Image.asset(
            'assets/$name/$i.jpg',
            //fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
          isVertical: false,
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 10.0,
        ),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text("$name $i",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 17,
                    fontFamily: 'Raleway',
                    color: Colors.black)),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 100.0),
              width: 120.0,
              height: 35.0,
              child: FlatButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  final status = await Permission.storage.request();
                  if (status.isGranted) {
                    final externalDir = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
                    FlutterDownloader.enqueue(
                      url: 'assets/$name/$i.dng',
                      savedDir: externalDir.path,
                      fileName: '$name$i.dng',
                      showNotification: true,
                      openFileFromNotification: true,
                    );
                  } else {
                    print("Permission Denied");
                  }
                },
                child: Text('Download',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 17)),
                textColor: Colors.white,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    side: BorderSide(
                        color: Colors.teal, width: 2, style: BorderStyle.solid),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ));
    i++;
  }
  return Column(children: list);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, at the end of the loop, `i` is `9`, that is why you see the behaviour you have. You have to make a local copy of `i` so this variable *stays* at the value it has for the loop when it gets captured:

```
while (i <= index) {
   final localIndex = i;

   // rest of your code, use localIndex here instead of i

   i++;
}
```